# excluding a tic number in scientific format

Tags: gnuplot

I am using `set format x '%.0e'` to have x-axis numbers in scientific format. Problem is, the `0` is shown as `0E+00`. How can I exclude `0` in scientific format?

Also other number has two digits in their exponential. Instead of `2E+01` I want  `2E+1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use a different format for the `y`-axis, use `%t` (mantissa to base 10) and `%T` (power to base 10). See the documentation of the 'format specifiers' (or type `help format_specifiers`).

To change a single entry, you can overwrite the automatic one using `set ytics add` and using the very same numeric value:

```
set yrange[0:100]
set xrange[0:100]
set format y '%.0tE%+T'
set ytics add ('0' 0)

plot x
```

Result (with 4.6.4):

[image]