# How to deal with y=0 tic for special formatted label

Tags: gnuplot

Suppose I have a script like this

```
set terminal png enhanced
set output "test.png"
set ytics format "%.1t 10^{%S}"
set ytics 5000
set mytics 5
set xrange [0:16000]
plot x
```

Which produces the following.
 [image: Sample figure]

I do wnat major tics as well as minor tics. However, the tic at zero looks ugly, so I would like to modify or delete it.

I tried `set ytics (5000,10000,15000)`. This is possible, but then I loose the minor tics. Also, I don't want to put the tics manually.

So a solution to this problem would

- remove the `y=0` tic or
- modify the `set ytics format` or
- adds minor tics for manual major tics, but according to the manual this is not possible.

An other solution that I didn't think of is of course also appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just overwrite the `0` tic with `set ytics ('0' 0)`:

```
set ytics format "%.1t 10^{%S}"
set ytics 5000
set ytics add ('0' 0)
set mytics 5
set xrange [0:16000]
plot x
```

[image]

See also [excluding a tic number in scientific format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19570596/2604213).

Comment: Thanks, I flagged my question as a duplicate, because I think the other question answers everything. However, I didn't find it earlier.