# in Gnuplot, how to set the origin point still using 0 except using costume format like 0x10^0?

Tags: gnuplot

I am googling this problem but not sure whether I am using the right key words to describe the problem.

The problem is this:
I want to plot the x-ticks with the format `1.0 x 10^6` and some thing like that, so I use the following code:

```
set format x "%1.1t {/Symbol \264} 10^{%T}"
```

And the result is like this:

[image]

The code works pretty fine except at origin point, which I want it still keeps 0 there, because you can see that `0x10^0` is still 0.

So is there anything I can do to solve this problem, or any web page or documents help solve this problem?

To be more specific, I want the plot look like this:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: `set xtics add('0.0' 0)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19569864/2604213

Comment: @MichaelO. Thank you! That really works!

Comment: @Christoph Thanks, that really works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of MichaelO. and  Christoph, I solved the problem.

In Gnuplot, just using

```
set xtics add('0.0' 0
```

can overwrite the original one with the new format of tics.

Here is the reference:

[excluding a tic number in scientific format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569864/excluding-a-tic-number-in-scientific-format)